# Error in mutiple if statements

Tags: r, if-statement

I am writing the following code in R but it gives me an error

```
S=function(x,a){
if(x<=a) {return (g)}
    else 
        if (a < x <= b) {return(h)}

> Error: unexpected '<=' in:
> "
>    else if (a < x <="
>                   else (return(i))
>    }
```

How do I correct it?

Comment: maybe you mean (a<x)||(x<=b) or maybe (a<x)&&(x<=b) ?

Comment: Why are you comparing x and a twice?

Comment: Why is this labeled with the "R" tag? This looks like javascript or something.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have rewritten your function to compile and eval, but I have no idea what it does for your problem.

```
S=function(x, a, b){

    if (x <= a){
        return(a)
    }
    else if ((a < x) && (x <= b)){  # break up the compound into two tests
        return(a)
    }
    else{
        return(a)
    }

}
```

You need to pass `b` and I don't know what `h,g` were, but they weren't being assigned in your function declaration.

```
> S(1,2,3)
[1] 2
```